# Easiest way to get a framebuffer like window in X? With Python? With XCB?

Tags: x11, framebuffer

What I'd like to do, in the simplest way possible, is to get a simple framebuffer like object to write to.

To elaborate, I'd like to be able to just write code like

```
typedef struct {
   ...
   uint32_t stride; // Number of items to skip to get to same pixel on row below
   uint32_t *pixels; // Pixel data
   ...
} framebuffer_thing;

#define PX(x,y) ((stride * (y))+(x))

void updateFb(framebuffer_thing);

myfunc(framebuffer_thing f) {
  for(i=0;i<100;i++) f.fb[PX(10+i,20+i)]=0xff000000+i*0x00010000; // To write pixels into my buffer
  updateFb(f); // To update the display if necessary
}
```

and ideally, I'd also like to have it interactively useable from Python.  Does anybody know of code that does this that already works, or how to go about writing it?

Comment: Have you looked at python-xlib?

Comment: That one slipped my attention.  Thanks.